# django widget as argument

Tags: python, django

```
 password = forms.CharField(label=('Password'),
    widgets={
        forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), 
        forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        })
```

Hello, I'm writing a login form in Django. I want to use two parameters on my widget, the code above doesn't work. I could write:

```
password = forms.CharField(label=('Password'),
    widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
```

this would work but I also want to add the class attribute. What can I do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding class to your field you can also do like this.Specifying a class name within a **init** function:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'classname'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `attrs` argument to the `PasswordInput` constructor:

```
password = forms.CharField(label=('Password'),
                           widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                                            render_value=False,
                                            attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```